# Transform a double into an int without losing numbers using c #

Tags: c#, double

I have a list of double and I have to remove the comma from those that have a decimal digit other than 0.

For example if I have 54.0 I do nothing, while if I have 6.7 I would like to turn it into 67.

Comment: .... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried other things but not what Markus offered me.
I do not understand why asking for help, perhaps for a seemingly simple thing, triggers the frantic desire to lower the reputation.
If I were super expert, I would not even have signed up for the forum.

Comment: @fede186 the issue is the question isn't clear enough, your example is very constrained e.g. what do you do if the number is `6.6535`? Does that become `66535` or does it truncate to `66`? What happens if the number is too large to convert to an int? What are the boundaries? When you ask a question you need to think about it from our perspective who have no idea how your application works.

Comment: you're getting downvotes because you do not show any research or effort to solve your own problem. try viewing your question through our eyes, it looks like you just want a piece of code written for you. and stackoverflow **is not** a code writing service

Comment: However it is so badly written that Markus wrote me after a second with the right solution.
I apologize immensely for ruining the philosophy of the forum but I believed that you could ask for help without being judged.

Comment: you can, but you have to play by the rules like any other person who asks a question. consider reading [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you dont want downvotes. we do not want to lower your reputation, we want you to learn

Comment: @fede186 FWIW as much as Markus answer works for you it would have been purely based on the example you gave, as noted in my previous comment it would fail for any number larger than a max `Int32` e.g. `2.147483648` would throw. This is why it's important to know the rules :)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could update your post with the expected result for the following inputs. 54.0 54,0 54.1 54.10 54,10 0.1 67 67.0 67.1 67.01 67.10 . _That might help us to understand your problem better._

Comment: Your comment about trying other things other than what Markus offered suggest that it is all that you want. I'm assuming in the case of 54.10 would have the expected output of 541 rather than 5410 and 0.1 would be 1 rather than 01?

Comment: Please, I ask how I can improve this post since now I have been banned from asking for more.
I also ask for help because I'm not good with English but for work I need to use this forum.
I am also willing to delete this post.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var i = Convert.ToInt32(d.ToString().Replace(".", ""))
```

Update: Accoring to some comments with some error handling

```
var d = 2.147483648;
//Replace , and . for international usability
var temp = d.ToString().Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty);
if (temp.Length < 10) {
     var i = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
} else {
     //there is a big change that the number is not fitting into a int => Do some error handling or use a long or Keep the string or ...
}
```